# Why do threads continue to run after application has exited?

Tags: python, multithreading

The following is a Python application which spans a few threads, then spawns a new process of itself and exits:

```
from pprint import pprint    import os
import random
import signal
import sys 
import threading
import time


class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class CallThreads(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
        self.target(*self.args)


def main(args):
    print("Hello, world!")
    letter = random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
    count = 0 
    while count<3:
        count += 1
        name = Name(letter+str(count))
        t = CallThreads(provider_query, name)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        print("------------")

    print("Time to die!")
    os.system('python restart.py')
    sys.exit(0)


def provider_query(name):
    while name.name!='':
        print(name.name)
        time.sleep(1)


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    main(sys.argv)
```

I expect that after the process exits, the threads associated with it would cease to function. However, running the above program on Kubuntu Linux shows me that the processes continue to run, even after the application has exited and a new process has spawned. I see this as the threads continue to output to stdout. Even if I comment out the `daemon` line, the processes continue to run.

**Why do the processes continue to run after `sys.exit()` has been called, and how can I get them to stop?** The issue occurs on Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 in Kubuntu Linux 12.10.

Comment: What does `restart.py` do? Are you sure the output you see isn't coming from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never made it to the sys.exit() call. `os.system('python restart.py')` blocks until restart.py completes - but that child restart.py blocks on yet another child restart.py, and etc... until you finally blow up the process table. You should see another restart.py in the process table about every 9 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Running the `os.system` command in another thread solved the issue.